# A stylistic question. Can I write "he was long the target of some particularly unrestrained polemics"?

Tags: phrases

Can I write "he was long the target/object of..." or do I have to write "he was the target/object of [some particularly unrestrained polemics] over a long period of time".

In the context I prefer the first variation stylistically, but am not sure if it is quite correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

long the x is quite elegant, literarily speaking.

Merriam Webster:

2
long
**adverb**
Definition of long
1 : for or during a long time

long a popular hangout

Comment: We’re looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Just providing a dictionary definition of "long" is insufficient. Although I agree with you, style is subjective, so I would find it quite difficult to justify my preference in an answer without quoting from respected authors. And I rather think that that is off topic on EL&U.

Comment: @David Just delete it if it is against the rules.